# How to show related post having same relationship filed under single CPT?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have registred two CPT.

1= Exam
2= Exam Type

Here i have added relationship filed to exam {1st} CPT. CPT 2 have 20-30 posts.

Now I want show related posts under 1st CPT from same cpt having same relationship filed.

I tried everything but nothing worked.

Comment: There's not really a way of helping without seeing your code.  I'd suggest from what you've described though that "Exam Type" shouldn't be it's own CPT.  It should be a custom Taxonomy.  Wordpress has the relationship already built in. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It may seem like we are taking the easy way out but, if you want an answer. we need to know what the two CPTs are and how you want them to relate. i.e. I have CPT(cats) with a relationship field that relates to the second CPT(kittens) by a field named bread. The code really does help so we can see the settings for each CPT.